# Update UI constraints in Xcode 8 for a specific device

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, constraints, ios-autolayout

As you can see on the image below my View Controller is packed with labels, everything looks good on iPhone SE but not on a larger screen phone. Is it possible to increase space between UI elements on iPhone 6,7,+ but keep same on SE without implementing Scroll View?

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty OK. You can make the "START BUTTON" to be at the more bottom using constraints but this is totally normal. It is like this because the cell has too low height and on bigger screens there is more space for things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stack View, it will automatically set space for every device. Embed labels in stack view (Editor -> Embed In -> Stack View) and choose Distribution property that works for you ("Fill Equally" or maybe "Equal Spacing"). You can embed any view - also stack view (so you can have 12 stack views with label and result and embed them in external stack view for proper row spacing).

[image: iPhone SE]
[image: iPhone 7 Plus]